# Endeca. 10.2-11.2 content migration

Tags: oracle, migration, endeca

We are migrating our Endeca Experience Manager content from 10.2 (3.1.2) version to 11.2 version.

First, we deployed standard Endeca application.

Then, We were trying to perform the following steps according to the documentation:

1. Migration from 3.1.2 to 11.0 (using appropriate migrate-workbench script which produces export-site.xml)
2. Migration from 11.0 to 11.1 (using appropriate migrate-workbench script which produces export-site.xml)
3. Migration from 11.1 to 11.2 (by applying previously generated export-site.xml)

After all of the steps above are complete we are trying to reach XM URL and what we are getting:

```
org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: 
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspExceptionInternal(JspServletWrapper.java:560)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:496)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:448)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspServletWrapperAdapter.service(JspServletWrapperAdapter.java:59)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:173)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:388)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:358)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:170)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:456)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:529)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
```

Moreover,
We checked that '{app_name}/config/import/content/' does not really contain any new content we're trying to import.

Are our steps right? Is there any different way to perform such kind of migration?

BTW, can we run exportApplication command on older versions of Endeca (prior to 11.0) in order to retrieve .zip archive with desired content?

Answer (score 0):

As part of step-2 after `importSite` following commands needs to be executed:

1. `<Endeca_App>\control>runcommand.bat IFCR exportApplication <path_to_be_exported>\CRS-export true` -  This would generate 11.1 compatible endeca content xml under import directory.
2. Create a new folder under `pages` with "Siteid" name and move all folder under `pages` to "Siteid" folder.
3. Run importApplication: `>runcommand.bat IFCR importApplication \CRS-Export`

Above steps would start showing all content in XM.

**Note:** 11.1 and 11.2 Endeca contents are same, hence same export folder can be migrated to 11.2 as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! So, do we need to deploy 11.0 application as well in order to run this "exportApplication" command you mentioned from there?

Comment: you need to deploy to 11.1 not in 11.0 to run exportApplication.